# Why is a DateTime field always written as ZERO in my WPF app with EF6?

Tags: mysql, wpf, entity-framework-6

I'm writing a program that stores text messages from a smartphone in a database.

I created a table in my MySQL database like so:

> CREATE TABLE `sms` ( 
>    `smsID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
>    `messageDate` datetime NOT NULL, 
>    `text` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL, 
>    `number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
>    `senderID` int(11) DEFAULT '0', 
>    `taskID` int(11) DEFAULT '0', 
>    `messageType` int(11) DEFAULT '0', 
>    `hasReply` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0', 
>    PRIMARY KEY (`smsID`), 
>    KEY `date` (`messageDate`) 
>  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=54 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

I'm creating and storing new objects for incoming text messages, in C# with the following code:

```
DbContext db = new DbContext();

var message = new sms();
message.taskID = taskID;
message.senderID = senderID;
message.messageDate = this.MessageDate;
message.number = this.Number;
message.text = this.Text;
message.messageType = MessageTypes.TYPE_INBOUND;

DebugLog.Log("Storing message with datetime: " +
message.messageDate?.ToLongTimeString());

db.sms.Add(message);
db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

All the data are stored correctly, except for the `messageDate` field (which I double checked: is not `null` at the point of calling `SaveChangesAsync`). It is always stored as '00-00-0000 00:00' or the default date set if it is set in the DB table.

Which makes sense when we take a look at the generated queries from the EF-log:

> Storing message with datetime: 11:37:29
> Opened connection at 20.09.2017 11:37:28 +02:00
> Started transaction at 20.09.2017 11:37:28 +02:00
> SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI';INSERT INTO `sms`(
> `text`, 
> `number`, 
> `senderID`, 
> `taskID`, 
> `messageType`, 
> `hasReply`) VALUES (
> @gp1, 
> @gp2, 
> 1227, 
> 122138, 
> 1, 
> 0);
> SELECT
> `smsID`, 
> `messageDate`
> FROM `sms`
>  WHERE  row_count() > 0 AND `smsID`=last_insert_id()
> -- @gp1: 'some text' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 5)
> -- @gp2: 'HIDDEN NUMBER' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 14)
> -- Executing at 20.09.2017 11:37:28 +02:00
> -- Completed in 1 ms with result: EFMySqlDataReader
> Committed transaction at 20.09.2017 11:37:28 +02:00
> Closed connection at 20.09.2017 11:37:28 +02:00
> Disposed transaction at 20.09.2017 11:37:28 +02:00

It seems like the field in question is queried from the database after the insert, just like the AUTO_INCREMENT `smsID`. No idea why.

This is really bugging me, since I don't want to insert the current time but the actual time the message arrived, and I can't seem to find a solution.

Any tips would be great! Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is messageDate property defined in Fluent API or Data Annotations?  Is the Type set to datetime?  It isn't set to use AutoIncrementing key on this datetime field, right?

I would check if messageDate is part of your key.  I would also check if the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute is applied to the messageDate property via Data Annotations or via Fluent API.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, it helped me solve the problem. Or workaround it... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel Lorenz for his comment.

He mentioned that the datetime field my be part of the key.
Well, I created an index for it in the database, before generating the model in Visual Studio (database first).

To workaround this issue (doesn't feel like a solution):

1. I removed the index from the table (MySQL)
2. Removed the table from the model (VS C#)
3. Re-added the table to the model (VS C#)
4. Re-added the index for the table (MySQL)

Suddenly the query is generated correctly, and the date is stored correctly.

This feels like a bug to me, but I'm glad it works now ;)